# Display ForeignKey filed as a table in django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-2.0

I'm working on a project using Python(3.7) and Django(2.1) in which I have a model call `Category` which has a filed as `parent` of type `ForeignKey` to itself as `self`. It's displaying in the Django admin as a drop down, as there will be hundreds of PARENT categories, so we can't use a dropdown in such a situation, what I want to display a big table with a search option to select a category as parent.

Here's my `Category` model:

**From `models.py`:**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, default='')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self',
                               blank=True,
                               null=True,
                               related_name='children',
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('slug', 'parent',)
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"

    def __str__(self):
        full_path = [self.name]
        k = self.parent

        while k is not None:
            full_path.append(k.name)
            k = k.parent

        return ' -> '.join(full_path[::-1])
```

**And From `admin.py`:**

```
@admin.register(Category)
class CatAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter = ('parent',)

    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('assets/css/custom.css',),
        }
```

so, how can I achieve my required scenario in Django admin?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of table with search option you can use `autocomplete_fields` ( Select2 dropdown with search option available ) option in django admin.

Comment: any example or source?

Comment: in your CategoryAdmin in admin.py just add `autocomplete_fields = ['parent', ]`

Comment: it requires to add `search_fields` also, but when I add `search_fields` the search doesn't work.